# 'Class X' Attribute has no attribute Y

Tags: python, class, object, attributes

I am new to Python and not sure what am I missing here?

```
class Song(object):
    def __init__(self, lyrics):
        self.lyrics = lyrics

    def sing_a_song(self):
        for line in self.lyrics:
            print(line)

mysong = Song("My Name is ashish")

mysong.sing_a_song()
```

Comment: I think the edit just fixed it for you - you had `sing_a_song` not properly indented.

Comment: @alecxe Shouldn't the edit be rolled back then?